# Need help getting records from a custom object

Tags: visualforce, email, template

looking for some help with this.  I have a custom object named Annual_Sales_Targets__c with a master detail relationship to Contracts.  When a contract is activated, a workflow will kick off and send an email to various people.  The template is a visualforce template that creates a pdf with the contract details. I'm good up to this point.  I need help with querying the custom object to pull the corresponding sales targets and them as a table to the pdf.

Comment: Hi Marvin, what have you done so far? Do you have the Visualforce template in place? What does it do right now to extract and render the sales target information? This sounds like it could be done without code other than Visualforce.

Comment: @DavidReed, My template just extracts and renders the contract information to a pdf file within a table.  I have a second table to pull the sales targets, but I get an error when using "<apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Annual_Sales_Target__c}" var="lineItem">". Error: Invalid field Annual_Sales_Target__c for SObject Contract

Comment: @DavidReed, the link pointed me in the right direction.  My child relationship name for the custom object is actually Annual_Sales_Targets. I changed the value to Annual_Sales_Targets__r and it rendered everything properly.  thank you